# minipage 6 figures avoid mixing figures horizontally

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing, minipage

I looked deeply in here and I couldn't solve my problem. I have 6 figures which I want to separate each other with enough space for avoiding mix it. I have 2 figures, below another two and below another two, however 1 figure from 1 column is mixing with the other column. I wonder how to separate it for a better visualization. I tried with hspace with no result. I have to say I am using tikzpicture as well.

Here is my code:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \centering
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht] 
        \begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
        \centering
        \makebox[0pt]{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{scope}[every node/.style={circle,thick,draw}]
                \node (A) at (-10,4)   {N5192};
                \node (B) at (-7,3)    {Menor};
                \node (C) at (-7,6)    {Mayor};
                \node (D) at (-5,4)    {No CRG};

            \end{scope}

            \begin{scope}[>={Stealth[black]},
                        center coordinate every node/.style={fill=white,circle},
                         % every edge/

.style={draw=red,very thick}
                     ]
            \path [->] (A) edge[near start,sloped,bend right = 15, blue,very thick]   node [black, fill = white] {53}  (B);
            \path [->] (A) edge[sloped,bend left = 15, blue,very thick]   node [black, fill = white] {$3301$}  (C);
            \path [->] (A) edge[sloped, bend left = 15, blue,very thick]   node [black, fill = white]{$48$}  (D);
       \end{scope}

        \end{tikzpicture}%
    }\par

    \caption{This is my Caption}
    \vspace{8ex} 
        \end{minipage}
        \begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \makebox[0pt]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{scope}[every node/.style={circle,thick,draw}]
           \node (A) at (-10,4)   {N5192};
            \node (B) at (-7,3)    {Menor};
            \node (C) at (-7,6)    {Mayor};
            \node (D) at (-5,4)    {No CRG};

        \end{scope}

        \begin{scope}[>={Stealth[black]},
                    center coordinate every node/.style={fill=white,circle},
                     % every edge/.style={draw=red,very thick}
                     ]
            \path [->] (A) edge[near start,sloped,bend right = 15, blue,very thick]   node [black, fill = white] {53}  (B);
            \path [->] (A) edge[sloped,bend left = 15, blue,very thick]   node [black, fill = white] {$3301$}  (C);
            \path [->] (A) edge[sloped, bend left = 15, blue,very thick]   node [black, fill = white]{$48$}  (D);
       \end{scope}

        \end{tikzpicture}%
    }\par
     \caption{This is my second Caption}
    \vspace{8ex}

        \end{minipage}
          \begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \makebox[0pt]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{scope}[every node/.style={circle,thick,draw}]
            \node (A) at (-10,4)   {N5192};
            \node (B) at (-7,3)    {Menor};
            \node (C) at (-7,6)    {Mayor};
            \node (D) at (-5,4)    {No CRG};

        \end{scope}

        \begin{scope}[>={Stealth[black]},
                    center coordinate every node/.style={fill=white,circle},
                     % every edge/.style={draw=red,very thick}
                     ]
            \path [->] (A) edge[near start,sloped,bend right = 15, blue,very thick]   node [black, fill = white] {53}  (B);
            \path [->] (A) edge[sloped,bend left = 15, blue,very thick]   node [black, fill = white] {$3301$}  (C);
            \path [->] (A) edge[sloped, bend left = 15, blue,very thick]   node [black, fill = white]{$48$}  (D);
       \end{scope}

        \end{tikzpicture}%
    }\par
     \caption{This is my third Caption}
    \vspace{8ex}
        \end{minipage}
          \begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \makebox[0pt]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{scope}[every node/.style={circle,thick,draw}]
        \node (A) at (-10,4)   {N5192};
            \node (B) at (-7,3)    {Menor};
            \node (C) at (-7,6)    {Mayor};
            \node (D) at (-5,4)    {No CRG};

        \end{scope}

        \begin{scope}[>={Stealth[black]},
                    center coordinate every node/.style={fill=white,circle},
                     % every edge/.style={draw=red,very thick}
                     ]
            \path [->] (A) edge[near start,sloped,bend right = 15, blue,very thick]   node [black, fill = white] {53}  (B);
            \path [->] (A) edge[sloped,bend left = 15, blue,very thick]   node [black, fill = white] {$3301$}  (C);
            \path [->] (A) edge[sloped, bend left = 15, blue,very thick]   node [black, fill = white]{$48$}  (D);
       \end{scope}

        \end{tikzpicture}%
    }\par
    \caption{This is my fourth Caption}
    \vspace{8ex}
        \end{minipage}
        \begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \makebox[0pt]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{scope}[every node/.style={circle,thick,draw}]
        \node (A) at (-10,4)   {N5192};
            \node (B) at (-7,3)    {Menor};
            \node (C) at (-7,6)    {Mayor};
            \node (D) at (-5,4)    {No CRG};

        \end{scope}

        \begin{scope}[>={Stealth[black]},
                    center coordinate every node/.style={fill=white,circle},
                     % every edge/.style={draw=red,very thick}
                     ]
            \path [->] (A) edge[near start,sloped,bend right = 15, blue,very thick]   node [black, fill = white] {53}  (B);
            \path [->] (A) edge[sloped,bend left = 15, blue,very thick]   node [black, fill = white] {$3301$}  (C);
            \path [->] (A) edge[sloped, bend left = 15, blue,very thick]   node [black, fill = white]{$48$}  (D);
       \end{scope}

        \end{tikzpicture}%
    }\par
    \caption{This is my fifth Caption}
    \vspace{8ex}
        \end{minipage}
        \begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \makebox[0pt]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{scope}[every node/.style={circle,thick,draw}]
        \node (A) at (-10,4)   {N5192};
            \node (B) at (-7,3)    {Menor};
            \node (C) at (-7,6)    {Mayor};
            \node (D) at (-5,4)    {No CRG};

        \end{scope}

        \begin{scope}[>={Stealth[black]},
                    center coordinate every node/.style={fill=white,circle},
                     % every edge/.style={draw=red,very thick}
                     ]
            \path [->] (A) edge[near start,sloped,bend right = 15, blue,very thick]   node [black, fill = white] {53}  (B);
            \path [->] (A) edge[sloped,bend left = 15, blue,very thick]   node [black, fill = white] {$3301$}  (C);
            \path [->] (A) edge[sloped, bend left = 15, blue,very thick]   node [black, fill = white]{$48$}  (D);
       \end{scope}

        \end{tikzpicture}%
    }\par
    \caption{This is my sixth Caption}
    \vspace{8ex}
        \end{minipage}
   \end{figure}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: There are a couple of errors in the code that you could fix. The third node misses its label, and the `every edge` style in the second scope has an empty line that shouldn't be there.

Comment: That said, the obvious solution is to reduce the size of each figure slightly.

Comment: sorry, It was a mistake when I copied the code. How can I reduce the size? there is not \includegraphics where I can use the scale option.. @TorbjørnT.

Comment: GOT IT! just type \hspace{0.5cm} after \end{minipage} and before \begin{minipage}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can scale a `tikzpicture` by adding `scale=<number>` to the environment options, e.g. `\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.75,...]`. Another way would be to change the unit vectors, by saying e.g. `\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.8cm,y=0.8cm]`. The default for both is  `1cm`.

For this case you could alternatively change the coordinates of the nodes, to bring them a bit closer together. For example change the x-coordinate of `Menor` and `Mayor` to `-8`, and that of `No CRG` to `-6`. Or something like that, haven't tested.

As you discovered you can just add `\hspace{<length>}` between the `minipage`s on the same line. However, you will have a lot of overfull hbox warnings in your log. If you care about those, reduce the size of the `tikzpicture` a bit as described above, and do something like the code below: Reduce the width of the `minipage`s to a bit less than `0.5\linewidth` and add `\hfill` between them. This way there will be a bit of space between them, and they wont overflow the line.

If you reduce the size of the `tikzpicture`s you don't need the `\makebox` trick either.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe} % prints a frame around the text area
\usepackage{tikz}
\centering
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\newcommand\ThisAddsTheFigure{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  %x=0.75cm,y=0.75cm
  scale=0.8
 ]
        \begin{scope}[every node/.style={circle,thick,draw}]
            \node (A) at (-10,4)   {N5192};
            \node (B) at (-7,3)    {Menor};
            \node (C) at (-7,6)    {Mayor};
            \node (D) at (-5,4)    {No CRG};
        \end{scope}

        \begin{scope}[>={Stealth[black]},
                    center coordinate every node/.style={fill=white,circle},
                     % every edge/.style={draw=red,very thick}
                 ]
        \path [->] (A) edge[near start,sloped,bend right = 15, blue,very thick]   node [black, fill = white] {53}  (B);
        \path [->] (A) edge[sloped,bend left = 15, blue,very thick]   node [black, fill = white] {$3301$}  (C);
        \path [->] (A) edge[sloped, bend left = 15, blue,very thick]   node [black, fill = white]{$48$}  (D);
   \end{scope}

    \end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht] 
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.48\linewidth}
    \centering
    \ThisAddsTheFigure%
\caption{This is my Caption}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.48\linewidth}
\centering
    \ThisAddsTheFigure
 \caption{This is my second Caption}
    \end{minipage}

\bigskip

      \begin{minipage}[b]{0.48\linewidth}
\centering
    \ThisAddsTheFigure
 \caption{This is my third Caption}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
      \begin{minipage}[b]{0.48\linewidth}
\centering
    \ThisAddsTheFigure
\caption{This is my fourth Caption}
    \end{minipage}

\bigskip

    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.48\linewidth}
\centering
    \ThisAddsTheFigure
\caption{This is my fifth Caption}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.48\linewidth}
\centering
     \ThisAddsTheFigure
\caption{This is my sixth Caption}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just type `\hspace{0.5cm}` after `\end{minipage}` and before `\begin{minipage}`.